# Formula for the $n^{th}$ positive integer that is not divisible by $2$ or $3$.

Tags: polynomials, sequences-and-series

The first few terms of this sequence are $1,5,7,11,13,17,$ ...
The numbers increase by alternating adding $4$ or $2$. From what I remember from Algebra II, since the second level of differences is constant, this should indicate that the sequence can be represented by a quadratic function. However, I am struggling to find such a function.

Comment: this may be useful https://oeis.org/A007310

Comment: There is no reason to think it can be represented by a quadratic function.

Comment: The first differences are $4,2,4,2,4,2 \dots$ and the second differences are $-2,2,-2,2 \dots$ and are not constant.

Comment: Could I write it as a piece-wise function, saying $3n-2$ if $n$ is odd, and $3n-1$ if $n$ is even?

Comment: The separate odd/even thing works - but there are ways of writing a single expression which works for all $n$. It depends on your application/requirement whether this is simpler and better or not.

Answer (score 4):

A mathematician might write it as:

$$T_n=6\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor +(-1)^{n-1}$$

Or, if you must $$T_n=\frac{6n-3+(-1)^n}{2} $$

This means there is a recursive formulation: $$T_{n+3}=T_{n+2}+T_{n+1}-T_{n}, T_1=1,T_2=5,T_3=7$$

$T_n$ can't be quadratic since $T_n-3n$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2):

The differences alternate between $2$ and $4$ which suggests a sequence with an average value of $3n+a$ where $a$ is a constant.

The variation is alternating between even and odd, so some multiple of $(-1)^n$ is indicated for the divergence from the average.

Fitting $3n+a+b(-1)^n$ gives $$3+a-b=1$$ and $$6+a+b=5$$

So that $9+2a=6$ and $a=-\frac 32$ and $b=\frac 12$

So we have $$s_n=3n-\frac 32+\frac 12(-1)^n$$

Comment: That's a great explanation! Is there a similar reasoning for the 7-rough numbers (i.e. not divisible by 2, 3, nor 5)? I posted here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586173/formula-for-the-nth-positive-integer-of-a-p-rough-sequence) a question and bountied it too. It would be great if you could help!

Answer (score 1):

From [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A007310), we have:
$$a(n) = \frac{6n + (-1)^n - 3}{2}$$