# Explicit formula for the $n^{th}$ positive integer of a $p$-rough sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

A ***p*-rough number**, or ***p*-jagged number**, is an integer whose smallest prime factor is $p$ (Finch, 2001).

The
$3$-rough numbers are the odd numbers. The $7$-rough numbers are numbers not divisible by $2, 3,$ or $5,$ that is:

$ \left \{1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, ...\right \} $.

- I am struggling to find an explicit formula for the 7-rough numbers
- I also wonder whether there is some recurrence or other method that can be used to find the $n^{th}$ number of a $p$-rough sequence for any possible $p$.

Thanks in advance!

---

**Edit**

I found on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A007775) the following formula by Gary Detlefs (Sep 15, 2013) for the $7$-rough numbers:

$$a(n) = \frac{6f(n) - 3 + (-1)^{f(n)}}{2}$$

where

$$f(n)= n + \lfloor\frac{n}{4}\rfloor + \lfloor\frac{(n+4) \mod 8}{6}\rfloor.$$

I wonder how it is derived and if it is possible to find an equivalent or alternative formula without the *floor* and *mod* operations in it.

Comment: Hint:  reduce each of the numbers in your sequence $\bmod 30$.  Why $30?$

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you for the hint! Unfortunately I am quite not familiar with modulo reduction. 30 is the product of the three primes and by adding or subtracting 30 to numbers in the sequence we still get numbers in the sequence. But then I am stuck...

Comment: Yes, modulo reduction is just finding the remainder after dividing by the modulus.  All the numbers in your list have one of eight remainders.  All the other numbers up to $30$ have a factor of $2,3,$ or $5$.  Your formula is one of those $8$ remainders plus some multiple of $30$.  If you add a multiple of $30$ to a number that has no factors $2,3,5$ you get another.  You should be able to prove that.

Comment: @RossMillikan I see, thank you for the explanation! Would the formula be $30 k ± (1, 7, 11, 13), k   ≥   1$? I was looking though for a function similar to this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928103/formula-for-the-nth-positive-integer-that-is-not-divisible-by-2-or-3, if that exists (?)

Comment: If $7$-rough means “an integer whose smallest prime factor is $7$”, is $11$ a $7$-rough number even though $7$ is not the smallest prime factor of $11$?

Comment: @robjohn Thanks for the comment! I think such definition points out that the prime factor of a $7$-rough number can be at the smallest $7$. For example, in $49$. It can be other prime factors but no smaller than $7$, i.e. no $2$, $3$, nor $5$.

Comment: Your formula misses $7,11,13$ but is otherwise fine.

Comment: There are several formulas given in the OEIS entry including my own. What is the problem with floor and mod? They express the periodicity of the sequence modulo 30 as in "a(n) mod 30 has period 8 repeating [1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]."

Comment: As an alternative, you can express the periodicity using sums of roots of unity raised to $n$th power. For example: $\lfloor n/2\rfloor = n/2 + ((-1)^n-(1)^n)/4.$ A similar formula using $30$-th roots of unity would work for your sequence.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments @Somos! It really seems what I was looking for regarding the formula for the 7-roughs. I will try to apply your hints. Unfortunately my knowledge in the field is very limited, especially with respect to the floor and mod functions. What I would like most is to understand the process of creation of the entire explicit formula, the intuition behind the process. If you could draft an answer by any chance, I would be very happy to read and follow your suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the $7$-rough numbers, using $8$-th roots of unity
you can get
$$ a_n = \frac{15}4 n +
\frac18 (-15+ (1+i)i^n+(-1)^n+(1-i)(-i)^n) +\\
\frac18 i^{n/2}( ((1-3i)-(2+i)\sqrt{2}) +
((1+3i)+(2-i)\sqrt{2})i^n+\\ ((1-3i)+(2+i)\sqrt{2})(-1)^n + 
((1+3i)-(2-i)\sqrt{2})(-i)^n). $$

Noticing the period $8$ behavior it is only a matter of solving for the coefficients of the $8$th roots of unity. A similar
method would work for any specific $p$-rough sequence.

More explicitly, in general, the $p$-rough integer
sequence has a linear average behavior. Subtracting off
this linear function leaves a purely periodic sequence.
Any such sequence can be expressed as
$\,a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} c_k (\zeta^k)^n$ for some coefficients $c_k$
where $\zeta^k=e^{2\pi i k/N}$
are the $N$th roots of unity and where $N$ is the period.
The coefficients can be found by solving a system of
$N$ linear equations as in the
[Discrete Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform).

In the case of $7$-rough, the linear function is
$\frac{15}4n$ and the remainder is a period $8$ sequence.

Notice that the $7$-rough numbers are all odd. Further,
$ (a(n+1) - a(n-1))/2$ is a bounded integer with
average value of $15/4$ and a period of $8$. Thus, a
good approximation is $a (n) \approx \lfloor 15n/4\rfloor.$
But this is always $\le 0$. A more balanced formula
is $a(n) = 3d(n) + e(n)$ where $d(n):=\lfloor 5n/4\rfloor,$ and $e(n+8)=e(n).$ We just have to find a formula for $e(n)$ which
depends only on $n \pmod 8$. The Detlefs formula is once such.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Is it $\zeta_k^{n}$ or $\zeta^{kn}$?

Comment: @Shootforthemoon Both are equivalent and commonly used.

Comment: k being used as an index in both cases, not as a power, right?

Comment: Dear @Somos, thanks again for the explanation! That really answers my first two points. If you could by chance address briefly how also the formula by Gary Detlefs can be derived, I'd be glad to read and learn starting from your hints!

Comment: @Shootforthemoon Okay. I will  try to get the Detlefs formula somehow. Wait for it.

Comment: Thanks for the useful addition!